# What alternatives I have for code hosting that can be accessed via CVS?

Tags: eclipse, cvs, sourceforge

I am looking for source code hosting.  Until now, I used SourceForge, but recently, I had a lot of downtime, password changing, etc., that prevented me using it for long periods.
I am looking for a good alternative. I prefer the CVS client since I am using Eclipse, and this is the only built-in source control client that is bundled with Eclipse.  Of course, it should be free.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We moved about 6 months ago to git from cvs and been very pleased with the move.  The latest version of eGit (Eclipse git plugin) works very nicely and does what we need to do on a daily basis.   The plugin just needs to be installed once after an Eclipse upgrade.  Since eclipse.org is slowly switching to git, I expect that it will eventually enter a main distribution.

The real benefit comes from the non-core functionality in terms of visualization, tooling support (in e.g. Hudson, which is many, many times faster with git than cvs) and distributedness.  The daily backup is just a remote mirror in a very distant location and so on.

I really like how github works which I would suggest for your primary work place.

Unless you have very good reasons to stay with CVS, I would encourage you to look at the various modern alternatives.  People recommend bzr, hg and git - which are the three I believe have critical mass these days - and which one fits you best is up to you to find out :)

Answer (score 3):

Use this moment in time to decide to leave CVS which is old and dangerous.  There are many more modern solutions which you should try.  Subversion, GIT, Fossil, Perforce, Mercurial and there are many online code hosting solutions for many of them.

There are third party plugins easily available for Eclipse for at least Subversion and Git and probably the others.

Its CVS you should move away from as well as Sourceforge.

Comment: why should I avoid sourceforge?

Comment: @ohadshai: that's what you've already decided for yourself, isn't it?

Comment: Not unreliable, but with some design decisions that time has shown to be less desirable.

Comment: @michael - indeed that is what I decided, but if no other cvs alternatives, should I stick to sourceforge?

Comment: @ohadshai: no, you should get it over with and finally use something better than CVS, like everyone else did 5 years ago. Installing a SVN plugin is really easy and quick. If you want to learn something useful, take a look at a really modern VCS like git.

Comment: @Thorbjorn - correct, but I guess at this point when their are options there is no reason to continue to use a source control system with those decision.

Comment: @Toby, if I'm correct, then your answer is incorrect and you should consider editing it.

Comment: @Toby, by the way, why is CVS dangerous?

Comment: Many would contend that the way CVS deals with merges is Dangerous to your code.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is time to move to Subversion, there is an eclipse plugin that I use for SVN which is very easy to use, and integrates just fine with eclipse.  http://subclipse.tigris.org/

There are plenty of SVN hosts out there like assembla.com which has free SVN hosting that I've used for several of my past projects

Comment: you owe yourself to investigate what a full-blown modern distributed versioning system will buy you and your team.

Comment: @Andersen Git is interesting and what I use on my personal projects.  My team at work just moved to SVN a year ago, so it doesn't look like they would change any time soon.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Assembla](http://assembla.com).  They currently have free SVN (Subversion) hosting right now, which comes with a code browser, email notifications, unlimited users, and other features.

It's been a really helpful addition to my toolset, and I highly recommend it.

Also, there are plug-ins for Eclipse, like [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) and [Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/).  I use Subclipse.  There is much debate about which is better, but so far Subclipse and Assembla have proved to be a good combination.